# webdriver import setSelected

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, testng, selenium-webdriver

How can I import setSelected and toggle commands in selenium Web driver.
I need to use that command to select a check box(I can't user element.click here)
I am using Java and testNG framwork.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These commands were deprecated long ago in the Selenium WebDriver API. There is no way to "import" them and make them just work. The correct way to change the value of a checkbox is with the `.click()` method. You say this method is unavailable to you, which usually indicates that the checkbox is not visible or enabled when you try to click on it. In such cases, the correct course of action is to make the checkbox visible or enabled however a user of your site would do so. You also have the option of using JavaScript to change the value of the checkbox, but that means you may be bypassing some of the code of your site.

Comment: Thanks JimEvans
I have to go for java Script solution.